# SCS Implant airport security fears

Tags: air-travel, airport-security, x-ray-machines

I'm having a spinal cord stimulator implant fitted soon and travel a couple of times a year to European destinations, although am planning a trip to the USA too:) My concern is although I will be given an i.d card stating I have the implant I will still be subjected to the scanner which I have been told will wipe the memory of the equipment. I have titanium rods/screws etc., in my leg/hips already and have been on the floor being subjected to a 'search' after I set the alarm off previously. Really nervous this will get worse once the implant is in place and I won't be going anywhere if they wipe the programmer. (The implant involves a battery (approx 6"x5") being inserted into the tummy wall with leads up the epidural space and then leads to the pain areas in your body so to an x-ray I will look extremely suspicious:/). Has anybody had problems going through airport security or do I get assisted travel?

Answer (score 5):

Security equipment and/or procedures at an airport should not wipe any data/settings from your SCS device according to the Mayfield Clinic; they suggest switching it off as a precaution.  [Full details are listed here](http://www.mayfieldclinic.com/PE-STIM.htm#.Ur2ab2RDv_A).  The paragraph most applicable to your query is quoted here:

"Just like a cardiac pacemaker, other devices such as cellular phones, pagers, microwaves, security doors, and anti theft sensors will not affect your stimulator. Be sure to carry your Implanted Device Identification card when flying, since the device is detected at airport security gates. Department store and airport security gates or theft detectors may cause an increase or decrease in stimulation when you pass through the gate. This sensation is temporary and should not harm your system. However, as a precaution, you should turn off your system before passing through security gates."

Comment: I am sure she is not just referring to a metal detector.